# How to add image at specific location in maps?

Tags: android, image, google-maps

In my project i want to add image at particular location in map.For that i used the following code.

```
public class Sample extends Activity {

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sample);

        // Get a handle to the Map Fragment
        GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(33.6671688,-117.9053506);

        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 15));

      //add overlay
        BitmapDescriptor image = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.categorymap);
        GroundOverlayOptions groundOverlay = new GroundOverlayOptions()
        .image(image)
        .position(sydney, 1000f)
        .transparency(0.1f);
        map.addGroundOverlay(groundOverlay);

    }
}
```

By using this code the map is displayed like the following screenshot.[image]

But my requirement is add the image at particular location like the following screenshot.For that i have latitude and longitude values also to show the map location.In that location i want to add the image like following screenshot.

[image]

So my question is,how to move the image from left to right like the above screenshot.I tried alot for doing this but didnt solve the issue.So please suggest me how to solve this problem.Thanks inadvance to all...

Comment: Why are you added this image into `GroundOverLay`? add this image into `Marker` icon

Comment: I tried marker icon also.If i add marker icon, the image is not working on zoomin and zoomout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get the exact positions of the corners of the building and uses the method

[public GroundOverlayOptions positionFromBounds (LatLngBounds bounds)](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlayOptions.html#positionFromBounds%28com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds%29)

Then it should scale with the mapzoom

Another way is to use [anchor](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlayOptions.html#anchor%28float,%20float%29)

EDIT:

```
GroundOverlayOptions groundOverlay = new GroundOverlayOptions()
    .image(image)
    .position(sydney, 1000f)
    .transparency(0.1f)
    .anchor(0.5, 0.5);
```

This will instead make the lat/lon to be in center of your image.

Comment: thanks for your quick response.Please tell me how to use these methods in my code

Comment: I tried this code,but i got the same output.the image is not moved.

Comment: what is the value of bounds in positionFromBounds method

Comment: The anchor is by default in the center of the image. In your case you should probably user anchor(0,0) instead. Then you have to make sure that the coordinates is correctly where you want to have the upper left corner of the image.